# Activity of M dwarf stars

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, star-formation, stellar-astrophysics, starspot

Why are M dwarf stars the most active (in terms of starspots and faculae) of all stars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magnetic activity is driven by a dynamo that relies on a combination of rotation and convection.

M dwarfs have large convection zones or are fully convective beyond spectral type M4. They also have much longer spin-down timescales than G- and K-dwarfs; billions of years rather than tens of millions of years.

This means that a large fraction of cool M dwarfs are rotating fast and have deep convection zones.

This is the basic reason, but it is still a very busy research area.